# C++ error C2227 on a list<std::wstring> object

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

So when the compiler gets to this code:

```
class SaveRecall : public BaseSql
{
private:
    std::list<std::wstring> *internalList;

    static int callback(void *data, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)
    {
        internalList->clear();
        for( int i = 0; i < argc; i++ ) internalList->push_back( argv[i] );
        return 0;
    }
...
```

it throws this error:

```
c:\projects\c++\midimod\source\BaseSql.hpp(37) : error C2227: left of '->clear' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
c:\projects\c++\midimod\source\BaseSql.hpp(38) : error C2227: left of '->push_back' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
```

Which makes no sense, because left of clear and push back is a list object, and I'm almost certain you can use clear and push back on lists.

I am using the MSVC2013 command line compiler.

Many thanks!

Comment: Since `callback` is `static`, you have no access to the class's member variables. Either make `internalList` a `static` member variable, or rework your code so that the `static` function calls a member function via a callback-supplied `this`, which in this case would be `data`.

Comment: I feel so stupid. Thank you so much, I guess I need some caffeine.

Comment: And now I'm getting LNK2019 / LNK1120 errors... *sigh* this is gonna be a long day.